# Can I rely on promises that a management coach will not share private information I provide?

Tags: management, privacy

Shortly after promoting me into a managerial position my boss hired a management coach - not just for me but also some of my colleagues who were also promoted.

We were assured the management coach was here to help us, answer questions and help us navigate being new managers. We were told anything we shared with the management coach would be kept in strict confidence and wouldn't be shared back to either my boss or our employer in general.

Despite the assurances I am still a bit skeptical and reserved about what I talk to or say to the consultant. I don't entirely believe/trust that what I say won't be directly or indirectly leaked back in some form or another.

Am I gullible thinking that they might be telling the truth and anything I do say will be kept in confidence. Or is this simply a tactic hoping to get folks to disclose their inner most private thoughts and opinions?

Have you been in either position (the consultant) or the manager and shared something in confidence. Were you pressured to share private information to them?  Or did you discover your confidence was broken by a consultant?

Comment: If I don't trust someone, they don't get my trust. They get superficial information only. Remember; the consultant has a contract with your company, not with you. In whose interests do you think they'll work?

Comment: I expanded the title to be more descriptive - feel free to re-edit.

Comment: Why do you feel you will need to share private information? I can't imagine they will be interested in anything other than your suggestions for how the business could manage things better. And as long as your answers are constructive and beneficial to the company, then there shouldn't be anything to worry about.

Comment: @musefan Say you had a difference of opinion about a particular topic or approach than your boss or your peers. If you share that with the consultant and the consultant shares it back with your boss it may paint you in an unfavorable light with your coworkers.

Comment: @Brad There is nothing wrong with having a different opinion to somebody. I mean, if your opinion is "I think my boss is a dick" then sure that will look bad. But if, for example, your opinion is "I think implementing process X will improve efficiency because of reason Y" then it's all good. Like I said: "constructive". Rule of thumb... don't say anything that you wouldn't say directly to your boss.

Comment: @musefan, That should be the case but some people don't like to be disagreed with regardless of sound reasoning, bosses and peers alike.  If OP needs to talk about that situation with the coach, this question is a fair concern

Comment: @musefan has hit the nail on the head so to speak. My managerial preferences and styles are different than my peers. I don't necessarily oppose them running their teams how they want to do so but I do have a problem with them trying to force their preferences on how I run my team. This may be something I want to explore/discuss with my coach but obviously i must do so carefully.

Comment: Common sense is that if you want to know the truth, people must be able to tell you the truth without negative consequences. Does your management have common sense?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no such thing as confidentiality in a business.  It’s for lawyers and priests (with some exceptions even there).

In this case, despite their assurances, you can expect things may still be shared with your management, the consultant’s direct employer.

So go easy, and be positive - benefit from the coaching but don’t say anything that would invite retaliation. (e.g. “How do I handle it when X happens,” not “This company is so jacked up that X happens all the time.”)

Comment: +1 If there is no written, legally-binding agreement with consequences for revealing information given in confidence, one should always assume that anything you say will be shared and behave accordingly. That might make the coaching less useful, but it's better than the alternative.

Comment: And in certain states, even priests are "mandated reporters". I witnessed a lawyer misunderstanding something he heard in confidence who then reported it to the police. If it is truly personal, it should only be shared with people who have proven that they can keep confidence.

Comment: Even if you have a written legal agreement, it's only worth anything if you have the ability to enforce it. So unless OP was able to prove that the other party broke it *and* was in a position to sue the management coach for damages, an NDA would be worthless.

Comment: It's unfair to assume that just because somebody *can* share things with the company they will, especially if they have promised that they will not.

Comment: You can either assume they may share or that they absolutely won’t. I think the odds are drastically in favor of the former so that’s how you have to handle it.

Comment: Actually, it's the same with lawyers. If your employer hired the lawyer and if your employer is paying their bill, make no mistake, that lawyer is working for your employer, not you.

Answer (score 6):

It depends.
Mostly on company culture and personalities of people involved.

I'm lucky to work in a company where I would trust this statement.

On the other hand, a consultant is somebody I would not share with anything more than what I'm sharing with my boss and colleagues.

> get folks to disclose their inner most private thoughts and opinions

it's a coach with whom I'd share those, completely different from a consultant

### update

As specified in the comment it'll be more a coach than a consultant.

To work efficiently with a coach you need sometimes to share information which you wouldn't share with your boss.
If your company thinks coaching seriously, they won't request information from coach which shouldn't be disclosed.

Anyway you can share your concern with your boss, if you get a honest answer and real actions / guarantees, you can be honest with the coach.

Otherwise indeed good idea to be cautious what to share.

Comment: I should clarify that this person is a management coach - but hired by my employer not by me. I can certainly see that the management coach's loyalties would be to the company paying their invoices. I guess I am asking if its wise to take them at their word that information divulged will be kept in confidence. The consensus seems to be don't say anything to them you wouldn't feel 100% comfortable saying to your boss.

Comment: @Brad, No, it wouldn't be wise at all. Do not assume that they'll keep your confidence. Share some information, it's not like you have a choice, but be guarded in what you share. That person is not your friend. That person doesn't work for you. But at the same time, do not argue with that person. Do not tell them that you don't trust them. Pretend that you do.

Answer (score 4):

Good answers already, but I'll just add a personal observation since you asked for that.

I have seen situations such as you described, and often the boss would get a report almost immediately.

I have never seen real confidentiality whether it's a consultant like this or an anonymous form. I've seen people sacked over things they have said in confidence or wrote on anonymous forms. One was sacked within 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not paying the bill, assume it's not confidential.  I've heard of situations where management coaches went right back to supervisors with any negative feedback, and people getting fired as a result.  Coaches aren't like mental health or attorneys and there's no confidentiality, but ESPECIALLY when their client is the business and not you directly.

Comment: Again, attorneys are a horrible example. Their loyalty is to the person who pays their bill.

Answer (score -2):

The importance of trust is central to our corporate value of supporting each other as needed. Feedback is used to foster a relationship of transparency and mutual respect. Trust is a subjective sentiment that is often expressed by both parties. knowing this will help you define if you can trust Him / Her with your personal issues and mind you trust is earned

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).